# Power steering pump problem

Tags: power-steering, pump

I have a 2008 Honda Accord and for some reason pump keep over flowing with bubbles. I tried changing out the o-ring and replacing the fluid, but the new fluid comes out bubbling also. I don't know if I have to change the pump itself?

[image]

Comment: Is it losing fluid at all?  Did you change the o-ring in an attempt to stop the bubbles or was the o-ring seeping?

Comment: It could be the position of the return line in the aftermarket tank that is causing the bubbles. If it is system cavitation then it is the pump itself.

Comment: The pump is getting air ; most likely caused by low oil level.